# My server stops responding for a few minutes, then starts again. How can I track down why this is happening?

Tags: networking, dns

I’m running Ubuntu on an Odroid Single Board Computer.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.14.79-117 aarch64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
Last login: Thu May 10 02:00:02 2018 from 172.16.68.56
root@odroid64:~# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
root@odroid64:~#
```

The server runs PiHole that provides DNS and ad blocking for my entire network.  My router assigns this as the DNS server for all DHCP clients.  The server also runs OpenVPN, but there are no connections open when I am having the following issue:

I’ve started having problems where I can’t browse the internet.  I noticed I could ping google DNS 8.8.4.4 but pinging DNS names didn’t work.  My router points to my PiHole server for all DNS resolutions.  So then I noticed I couldn’t ping my PiHole server, much less remote in via SCP.  After a few minutes, without having changed a single setting anywhere in my network, everything starts working again.

Is there a log file somewhere that I can examine the time period where things stopped and started working again that might give me a clue as to why the server is non-responsive?

ETA: results from `free;vmstat;vmstat -s`

```
      1758596 K total memory
       107820 K used memory
       141756 K active memory
       191308 K inactive memory
      1317372 K free memory
        12516 K buffer memory
       320888 K swap cache
            0 K total swap
            0 K used swap
            0 K free swap
        37711 non-nice user cpu ticks
         1145 nice user cpu ticks
        12130 system cpu ticks
     57663028 idle cpu ticks
          295 IO-wait cpu ticks
            0 IRQ cpu ticks
         1816 softirq cpu ticks
            0 stolen cpu ticks
        25205 pages paged in
        16854 pages paged out
            0 pages swapped in
            0 pages swapped out
   1238810489 interrupts
     67902033 CPU context switches
   1525917646 boot time
        12904 forks
root@odroid64:~#
```

Comment: How much RAM? How much swap? Edit your post, don't comment, and show us the results of the commands `free;vmstat;vmstat -s`. Also, read `man free;man vmstat`

Comment: did you check ... syslog? systemd journal log?

Comment: @Rinzwind while I could find syslog, I’m not sure what to look for, and I’ve no idea what you mean by systemd journal log.  Is that a command or something else?

Comment: if you use systemd on that machine it has its own log with notice. example commands: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225401/how-to-see-full-log-from-systemctl-status-service

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the machine was trying to renew a DHCP address, even though it is setup as static!  Strange.  Probably there is something else involved.